# How to disable the right-click menu in the "Incubator(FP11)" version of flash player

Tags: actionscript-3

i want to know how to disable the right click menu in the "incubator(FlashPlayer 11)"?

As i know, in the old version, we can use set wmod is "opaque" then the right click menu could be disable by a javascript.

But, in the "Incubator" we must set the wmod is "direct" could use the hardware render. So, how to disable the right click menu in the "Incubator"?

Answer (score 1):

One method:

"Just add this to the html-file of the flashmovie, into the object tag of the flashmovie:

```
<param name=menu value=false>
```

That does it!"

Another method is to do so using AS3 code:

```
var custom_menu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
custom_menu.hideBuiltInItems();
_root.menu = custom_menu
```

Sources:

http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?t=299218
http://forums.creativecow.net/thread/190/859287

This is something a quick and easy google search can reveal rather easily.

Comment: Your method can only disable the build-in features, such as "Zoom". But I want the right-click menu can not be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Available since Flash Player 11.2, you should be able to simply suppress the default context menu like so:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK, function(e:Event):void{});
```

You can also download an [example from Lee Brimlow](http://www.leebrimelow.com/?p=3337) or [video guide](http://www.leebrimelow.com/?p=3253) if it helps.